# Same JS function for x php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, timer

I have X tables on my php page. In each, i've timer. These timers doesn't have the same duration. I would like to know how to refresh these timers (separatly) with one JS/AJAX function.

timer.php (i can't post the real code, just an example to allow you to understand)

```
<?php
  tab_number = X;
  for ($i=0; $i<=X; $i++) {
  $duration = MySQL query on duration with $i parameter. Return seconds for the timer.
  $time_left = php function to change seconds to min:sec and to decrease $time_left each seconds

// just keep in mind that my timer is working, all of above is an example, my problem is on refresh.

echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><div id="rem_time'.$i.'">' . $time_left. ' left</div></td>';
  echo '<tr>';
echo '<table>';
```

javascript function on same page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function refresh() {
    $('#rem_time').load('time.php #rem_time');
  }
  setInterval('refresh()',1000);
</script>
```

I would like to know if it possible to use my JS script for each rem_time1, rem_time2, ..., rem_timeX separatly

Comment: Because of i just want to refresh a TD of my html table, not all the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function timer(i, start_date, duration) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var date_now = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        var rem_time = duration - (date_now - start_date);

        // Times calculs
        minuts = parseInt(rem_time / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(rem_time % 60);

        if (rem_time >= 0)
            document.getElementById("rem_time"+i).innerHTML = minuts + ":" + seconds;
    }, 1000);
}
```

**PHP/HTML (mixed but syntax error)**

```
<table>
    for ($i=1; $i<X; $i++) {
        <tr><td>
            <div id="rem_time".$i.> <script> timer($i, '14:30:25', 600);</script></div>
        </tr></td>
    }
</table>
```

and it works :)

Thx all !

Comment: Click on the gray tick near your answer to validate it

Answer (score 0):

You could use data attributes on each table and query a php script with your ajax call. Here's an example using two tables with different timer counts:

**HTML**

```
<div id="table1" class="container">
    <table data-url="/path/to/script.php?table=1" data-timer="1000">
        <!-- Table content -->
    </table>
</div>

<div id="table2" class="container">
    <table data-url="/path/to/script.php?table=2" data-timer="500">
        <!-- Table content -->
    </table>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Here we select using the attribute, you could use a class or other
$('[data-timer]').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $parent = $this.parents('div.container');

    // Set interval will call the load function every x milliseconds
    setInterval(function(){
        // Now we use the table data attributes to load the
        // correct data with the correct inteval
        $parent.load( $this.attr('data-url'), function() {
            console.log( "Load was performed." );
        });
    }, $this.attr('data-timer') );
});
```

**PHP**

```
$table = $_GET['table']

if($table == '1'){
    // ouput table 1 html
}else{
   // output table 2 html
}
```